# Youtube API to fetch video thumbnail and download URL in iOS?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

How do I fetch video thumbnails and download URL from Youtube API in iOS?

When i queried the API by API key by **get_video_info** endpoint but it gave me every detail about videos expect the URL, why it is not returning me url?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no download URL in the Youtube Data API.If you are planning to play a youtube video using the API, try this [GitHub youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) to load a Youtube video using `loadWithVideoId`. You can also try this tutorial - [Building a Video Search App with YouTube API](http://www.appcoda.com/youtube-api-ios-tutorial), this shows how to display channel details, the video playlist of a channel, to search videos and channels, and lastly how to play the video. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, thanks for reply but problem remains the same. There are many apps on App store that perform download on youtube videos. I couldn't even imagine how they are doing it then. What do you think about download action they are performing very neatly @Mr.Rebot

Answer (score 0):

You can get the thumbnail using a simple call.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=cricket&part=snippet&maxResults=50&key=Your_key
You will get image with thumbnails key and downloading a Youtube video is against their policy and terms, But you can easily download any video.